# GameCenter in Unity project

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, game-center

I'm trying to implement GameCenter in my unity project. So far I have made an app in itunes connect and set up game center and a leaderboard.

The function below is calling within a UI button in unity.

```
public void ShowLeaderBoardGameCenter()
{
    Social.Active.ReportScore (1, "55379413", success => {
        Debug.Log(success ? "Reported score successfully" : "Failed to report score");
    });
    Social.Active.ShowLeaderboardUI ();

}
```

It works find to show up the leaderboard, but the score doesn't show.

I also have created a sandbox account for gamecenter which I currently use.

In my unity project it says "Leaderboard not found"??? - Hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    if (Social.localUser.authenticated) 
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        {
            ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI (leaderboard); // Show current (Active) leaderboard
        }
        #elif UNITY_IOS
        {
            GameCenterPlatform.ShowLeaderboardUI ("BallzBrickSmasher_Leaderboard", TimeScope.AllTime);
        }
        #endif
        }
```